# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," setting my react state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, charts

I want to edit the label property but when I try to do it with this *this.setState({chartData.datasets[0].label: 'Test'})* it throws me this error:
 P*arsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","*

```
state = {
    chartData: {
      labels: ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: '',
          data: [40, 32, 70],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 4
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataSet();
  }

  getDataSet = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/total_cases.csv");
    const dataSet = res.data;

    this.setState({chartData.datasets[0].label: 'Test'})
  }
```

Comment: The information you need to know is how to update nested state properties in React, which is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this for complex object.

```
 let object = { ...this.state };
 object.chartData.datasets[0].label = 'Test';
 this.setState(object);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
this.setState((oldState) => ({...oldState, chartData.datasets[0].label: 'Test'}))
```

May not solve your issue, but at least you won't overwrite your entire state.

Comment: Would that not equal trying to set `{'': 'Test'}` at the top level of the object?

Comment: You may need to desctructure the entire state.